# Операции с БД не в основном потоке

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, sqlite

Пытаюсь перевести все операции с БД в своем приложении(например операцию удаления данных из БД) в отдельный поток. Для этого я решил сделать переделать соответствующий метод удаления добавив создание и запуск Thread. Но этот метод не работает, удаляя запись только с экрана, но не с БД. Хотя до помещения его в метод run() все работало хорошо. С чем может быть связана проблема?

Метод для удаления записи из класса БД:

```
class runnableForDeleteOrder implements Runnable{
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
        long idOfDeletingOrder;
        runnableForDeleteOrder(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB,  long idOfDeletingOrder){
            this.sqlDB=sqlDB;
            this.idOfDeletingOrder=idOfDeletingOrder;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                sqlDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ NAME_OF_CONNECTOR_TABLE +" WHERE "+ IDSH_CONNECTOR_TABLE+"= '"+idOfDeletingOrder+"';");
                sqlDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ NAME_OF_TABLE_ORDERS +" WHERE "+ ID_TABLE_ORDERS+"= '"+idOfDeletingOrder+"';");
            }catch (IllegalStateException e){}}
        }
    void deleteOrder( SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, long idOfDeletingOrder){
        Thread t = new Thread(new runnableForDeleteOrder(sqlDB,idOfDeletingOrder));
        t.start();
    }
```

Использование метода:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    mDB = new MyDataBase(this);
    sqlDB = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
    long idOfChangeableOrder = Long.parseLong(((TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.tvId)).getText().toString());
        switch (item.getItemId()){
          case 1:
                mDB.deleteOrder(sqlDB,idOfChangeableOrder);
                llMain.removeView(ll);
                if(llMain.getChildCount() == 0){
                    llMain.addView(getMessageAtEmptyLayout());
                }
                break;
        }
        mDB.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Метод `deleteOrder` вызывается у экземпляра класса `MyDataBase`. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Но в deleteOrder() в любом случае создается и запускается новый поток, разве он зависит от того из какого обьекта его вызывать?

Comment: вы вызываете `deleteOrder` объекта `MyDataBase`, но показываете метод `deleteOrder` объекта `runnableForDeleteOrder`. То, что у двух классов методы называются одинакого не означает, что они делают одно и то же. Покажите код метода  `deleteOrder` объекта `MyDataBase`.

Comment: runnableForDeleteOrder это внутренний класс. Он вместе с методом deleteOrder находится внутри наследника SQLiteOpenHelper который называется MyDataBase.